# Why can't functions be directly used as lambdas in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin we can't write:

```
arrayOf(1,2,3).forEach(println)
```

But we have to instead call `forEach` using `::println`. This is because `forEach` expects a lambda, but `println` is a function. Why are these different types and is there any good reason why Kotlin doesn't automatically cast it for me like it does in Python?

**Update:**

There does seem to be a difference. Look at:

```
val addA: (Int)->Int = {it+1}
fun addB(i: Int) = i+1

fun main(args: Array<String>){
    var x: Int=0
    x.let(addA).let(::addB).let(::print)
}
```

The lambda doesn't need the `::`, but the function does

Comment: Very good question. May I suggest adding more tags (such as "lambda", "anonymous function", "methods", "function") in order to make it more visible (and also bump the question to the main page)? Alternatively, why not offer a small bounty? I would do it myself, but I have very little reputation, while yours is huge.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that a lambda and a function are different types. The only type which exists is a `function type` and a lambda is one way of instantiating a function. Here in the documentation are all the ways to get an instance to a function type https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type.

`::println` is a way if getting a reference to an existing declaration. So your question is why it is necessary to use `::`. Maybe it is just to have a consistent way of getting a function reference in other cases as when you want a reference that point to a member of a particular instance as `foo::toString`.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-function-and-property-references-since-11

Comment: Sure, but what is the reason that it is foo::toString rather than foo.toString in Python? What's the motivation there?

Comment: it is an operator used to explicitly get a member or a class reference. It can be used for reflection purposes also. Take a look at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html. I know that kotlin creators like explicity, so maybe that's the reason to create a specific operator for those use cases, but I'm just speculating now.

Comment: You can see here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#property-references that `::x` returns a `KProperty<Int>`. How could it be done without the `::` operator?