# Why can't the "`main`" function be declared as a lambda in Kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, methods, lambda, anonymous-function

The following trivial Kotlin code snippet

```
fun main() {}
```

compiles just fine, but the following

```
val main : () -> Unit = {}
```

makes the compiler complain that "No main method found in project.", while I was expecting them to be equivalent (I expect a programming language to be as conceptually uniform as possible).

> Why does this happen? Is it related only to `main`, or does this behaviour concern a larger class of functions? Is there some [subtle difference between declaring functions with "`fun`" and declaring them as lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61998996/4334680)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a subtle (or more than subtle) difference. Declaring it with `val` means that `main` is a property containing a reference to an anonymous function (which you defined with the lambda). If you define it with `val`, then when you call `main()`, you are actually calling the getter of the `main` property, and then using the `invoke()` operator to call `invoke()` on the return value of the property (the anonymous function).

Comment: I noticed the same behaviour in Scala; is its explanation the same as in Kotlin?

Comment: I don’t have any Scala experience. But if they have the same concept for properties, it’s probably the same concept.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, they are different things. To see that, let's take a look at roughly what the equivalent Java would be. I'll use JVM for examples in this answer, but the same principles apply to all of the other Kotlin backends.

```
object Foo {
  fun main() { ... }
}
```

This is roughly

```
class Foo {
  public static void main() { ... }
}
```

Again, roughly. Technically, you'll get a singleton object and a method on it unless you use `@JvmStatic` (I assume there's some special handling for `main` that produces a static function on JVM, but I don't know that for a fact)

On the other hand,

```
object Foo {
  val main: () -> Unit = { ... }
}
```

Here, we're declaring a property, which in Java is going to get implemented as a getter-setter pair

```
class Foo {
  // Singleton instance
  public static Foo instance = new Foo();

  public Supplier<Void> main;

  Foo() {
    main = new Supplier<Void>() {
      Void get() {
        ...
      }
    }
  }

}
```

That is, there isn't actually a `main` method. There's a `main` field which, deep down somewhere, has a function inside of it. In my example above, that function is called `get`. In Kotlin, it's called `invoke`.

The way I like to think of it is this. Methods in Kotlin (i.e. the things you define on objects that designate their behavior) are not themselves first-class objects. They're second-class citizens which exist *on* an object. You can convert them to first-class objects by making them into functions. Functions are ordinary objects, like any other. If you take an ordinary object, which may or may not be a function, and call it with `()`, then you're actually invoking the method `.invoke(...)` on it. That is, `()` is an *operator* on objects which really ends up calling a method. So in Kotlin, functions are really just objects with a custom `invoke` and a lot of syntax sugar.

Your `val` defines a field which is a function. Your `fun` defines a method. Both of these can be called with `()`, but only one is a genuine method call; the other is secretly calling `.invoke` on another object. The fact that they look syntactically the same is irrelevant.

As the old adage goes, functions are a poor man's objects, and objects are a poor man's functions.